# Ubuntu Server doesn't accept keyboard input at startup

Tags: server

I have a Ubuntu Server running since a few years. Today I was shutting it down because I needed it to move locations. Upon restarting, I cannot enter my password for disk encryption anymore. It is very strange. The server is headless and I only ever interact with it via keyboard or ssh.

I can confirm that the USB keyboard works because I can get into the BIOS and use the keyboard there. But when I boot into Ubuntu server and it asks me for decryption password, no matter what I do, it just stays at the password prompt. (I do understand that the password is not shown in clear text or * and yes I do enter it and then hit ENTER). This is super weird.

Any clues?

Comment: I note what you said about being able to use the keyboard in the bios, but just to be certain it’s not a hardware issue, do you have access to another keyboard you can try & in a different USB port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what happened (well, kind of): It seems to be only happening with the latest installed kernel 4.15.0-158-generic. If I boot into the one before that (4.15.0-151-generic) everything works as expected. So at least I have a good workaround. Still very strange and makes no sense to me...